# Allow only 1 value per key press

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, richtextbox

I have a `richtextbox` on a `windows form` the user can enter text into but it needs to be setup so that if the user holds down a key they only get 1 character.

e.g. if they `hold down A` then it will only input A and not `AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA` etc.

From the moment the key is down till the time the key is up I only want that to translate to 1 value.

Any ideas how I can achieve this ?

I guess I need to use `KeyDown` and `KeyUp` but I'm not sure past that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could subclass `TextBox` and override `OnKeyDown` and `OnKeyUp` methods. If there wasn't any `KeyUps` after `KeyDown`, just ignore it by setting `KeyEventArgs.SuppresKeyPress` to `true`. Check the code:

```
public class MyTextBox:TextBox
{
    bool down = false;
    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!down)
            base.OnKeyDown(e);
        else
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        down = true;
    }
    protected override void OnKeyUp(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyUp(e);
        down = false;
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can use `KeyUp` and `KeyDown` event handlers like this, note that the `SuppresKeyPress` is crucial:

```
bool down = false;
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
      if (down)
          e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
      down = true;
}

private void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
      down = false;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You are right about the `KeyDown` and `KeyUp` events. You can do it this way.

```
bool keyDown = false;
bool keyPress = false;

private void richTextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = keyDown;
    keyDown = true;
}

private void richTextBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    keyDown = keyPress = false;
}

private void richTextBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = keyPress;
    keyPress = true;
}
```

Comment: This is working for delete and backspace, which is great, but it doesn't work for keys like A, B, C etc ?